# TableView (xib) Header not properly positioned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting this issue with the tableView I have tried to set the clipping flag to yes and the cell clipping to yes as well and it doesn't appear to make a difference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bbgle5b05u5bzc/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2018.42.31.png?dl=0

Can anyone figure out what is going on ? I will provide more information as needed.
Note I did constrain the tableview like so

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c5j6rmv52ftg8u/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2018.48.33.png?dl=0

Edit it turns out the header is not positioning it's self.
at the top of the tableview.

Comment: You need to explain the image, since we don't know what it should look like. What is the view that has the cut off text? Is that a cell, a section header, something else?

Comment: Have you implemented tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: and returned a height big enough for your text? What is the view with "Day 1 - Core" (is that a cell)?

Comment: Hey sorry dropbox gave the wrong link let me fix that sorry

Comment: Link is fixed that was the wrong screen

Comment: It looks like the same wrong image to me. I've asked you several questions. If you want help, please answer them.

Comment: @rdelmar, so if you take a look in my post it appears that the header for the tableview is offset by a y value ? for some odd reason. This link to be exact https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bbgle5b05u5bzc/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2018.42.31.png?dl=0

It does clip at where the table view ends in this image 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c5j6rmv52ftg8u/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2018.48.33.png?dl=0